# Hide some details and show once registered in mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I create one page for contact details. Here when user paid then only show this contact details. how to do it? is possible way in jquery?

**STEPS:**

1. when i open the page, what are all the registered details in database the details are all show.
2. Then click one user link, it will go to contact details.
3. If some one see the data, have to pay some amount. when their payment

Comment: more elaboration required mate

Comment: what elaboration need?

Comment: don't understand 'If some one see the data, have to pay some amount. when their payment' when their payment what?

Comment: Payment means to see the details they have to pay some amount. once they registered then their id goes to payment page. they paid some amount, the hidden details should not hide. it will show only that person. when other person see it will hide.

Comment: Try these links: 1. [Accordion | jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) 2. [Dialog | jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)‎

Answer (score 0):

Request the data from your MVC controller using jquery: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Return the data from your controller as json using jsonresult: http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx

Next display the data in the page.

To hide you can simply use jquery http://api.jquery.com/hide/:

```
$('youreleme').hide();
```

Comment: i already displayed the data. only the problem is hide when payment finished/